# Create input table parameter for calling Oracle stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use an Oracle stored procedure that takes `TABLE of NUMBER` for two of its inputs. I'm calling it from C# and I'd like to use `System.Data.OracleClient` as opposed to ODP.NET because that's approach my company is currently taking, so please avoid answers utilizing ODP.NET. I haven't been able to create acceptable input parameters. What should I do?

Comment: If changing the framework to accommodate ODP.NET is out of question, can you take two comma delimited strings (varchar2) values in the stored procedure and proceed from there?

Comment: I do have control over the stored procedure's parameters though I'm not fond of that approach or its variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a few years since I've tried anything like this, but historically, passing esoteric types (arrays, user-defined types, tables) to .NET managed data providers has been poorly supported at best. I doubt `System.Data.OracleClient` supports this. You'll probably have better luck with ODP.NET.

Worth noting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7.aspx

Comment: Agreed; however, my company uses a framework that employs `System.Data.OracleClient`, and there's no simple work-around.

Comment: This is one of those points in your development process where you have to make a decision -- simplify your stored procs or change your data provider. These may be the only options. Sorry!